# waiting time which excludes time taken by the program

Tags: python, pandas, time, sleep

Im trying to simulate a client sending data in real-time.  The data is rows of a dataframe, which is indexed by the amount of time that lapses between each row of the dataframe. I had

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    time.sleep(index)
    sender(client, row)
```

where sender is a function to send things to the server;

```
def sender(socket, msg):
    message = pickle.dumps(msg) # encodes messages into bytes, so it can be sent
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = pickle.dumps(str(msg_length))
    msg = bytes('{:<64}'.format(msg_length),FORMAT)+message
    socket.send(msg)
```

but since the program takes a few milliseconds to actually send the message, and do some other calculations, it starts to drift away from the propper times its meant to send the data at; the time of the program compounds.

How can I make it wait the correct amount of time, accounting for the fact that the program isn't instant?

i tried:

```
delay = timedelta(0)
start = datetime.now()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    delay += timedelta(seconds=index*60*24*60/60)
    while datetime.now() < start + delay:
        pass
        
    sender(client, row)
```

but its not working, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's sleep function:

```
import time

def print_hello_after_60_milliseconds():
     time.sleep(0.06)
     print('hello')
    
print_hello_after_60_milliseconds()
```

```
def print_hello_after_3_seconds():
     time.sleep(3)
     print('hello')
    
print_hello_after_3_seconds()
```

500 ms would be time.sleep(0.5). But this solution is only helpful if you want to wait a fixed amount of time, I don't know whether you want to wait dynamically depending on a condition.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i tried using sleep time, but the programs time compounds to push it off later and later